# how to select in select postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column named jenis_kelamin I want to display the gender of male and female in a select query. I have a query like this but the data that comes out is still wrong, what is the correct way?

```
SELECT distinct mj.id, mj.nama_pd,
(select distinct count(jenis_layanan) from public.isian_kuis 
 where jenis_kelamin = 'Laki' ) as jumlah_laki,
 (select distinct count(jenis_layanan)
 from public.isian_kuis
 where jenis_kelamin = 'Perempuan' ) as jumlah_perempuan
 FROM public.master_jabatan mj
 join isian_kuis ik on ik.jabatan_id = mj.id
  group by mj.id,mj.nama_pd
   order by mj.id;
```

I have an example of the image of my query, this is still wrong[image]

The correct data is that at ID 30 it has two men and one woman, in ID 29 there is only one woman
[image]

Comment: Provide some sample data (5-10 rows) as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (code-formatted text, not picture!) and desired output for this data.

Comment: PS. Your subqueries returns one row each (no GROUP BY), so DISTINCT makes no sense in them.

Comment: If that's what you're getting, then there is no `master_jabatan`
 whose ID is equal to the `jabatan_id` of any `isian_kuis`

Comment: @akina I've changed my question, hope you can understand

Comment: As I have said, pictures are not useful, provide textual sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use nested select just use `Group By` like this:

```
SELECT distinct mj.id, 
  mj.nama_pd, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN jenis_kelamin = 'Laki' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS jumlah_laki,
  SUM(CASE WHEN jenis_kelamin = 'Perempuan' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS jumlah_perempuan
FROM public.master_jabatan mj
join isian_kuis ik on ik.jabatan_id = mj.id
group by mj.id,mj.nama_pd
order by mj.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use conditional aggregation which looks like:

```
SELECT mj.id, mj.nama_pd, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE jenis_kelamin = 'Laki')AS jumlah_laki,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE jenis_kelamin = 'Perempuan')  AS jumlah_perempuan
FROM public.master_jabatan mj JOIN
     isian_kuis ik 
     ON ik.jabatan_id = mj.id
GROUP BY mj.id, mj.nama_pd
ORDER BY mj.id;
```

Note that it is very, very rare to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.  This might slow down the query.  And `FILTER` is standard SQL so is a good way to implement this.